# Loop though a specific shell command

Tags: powershell, unix, terminal

I would like to check all accounts that they do have access to a server partition for how much budget they have consumed. The command to do that is the following:

```
accuse -u "accountName0040"
```

There are in total 30 accounts and they all follow the same naming with different indexing. I would like to loop through all these accounts run this command and extract the outcome. How can I do that thing with shell script?

My idea is to do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while #"a button is pressed"
COUNTER = 40
do
    accuse -u "accountName"COUNTER
    echo # the outcome of the command
    COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1))
done
```

Comment: Is this question about PowerShell? If not you should remove the PowerShell tag.

Comment: Try in PowerShell: `40..59 | foreach { accuse -u "accountName00$_" }`

Comment: Please learn to post code that has been 'proofed" at https://shellcheck.net. Good luck.

Comment: There are other things I would change but your main problem is this line is missing a dollar-sign to get the value of the variable: `accuse -u "accountName"COUNTER`. That should be `$COUNTER`.

Comment: There is also the problem that if the numeric portion of the user name is padded with leading zeroes to be four digits then your solution is still wrong even if you add the missing dollar-sign because the first time through the loop will construct the string "accountName40", not "accountName0040". You should get into the habit of adding debug print statements to understand what is going on. For example, insert `name="accountName"COUNTER` then `echo $name >&2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `seq -f` to generate the list of account identifiers:

```
#!/bin/bash
START=40

for aid in `seq -f "accountName%04g" $START $(($START + 29))`
do
  accuse -u $aid
done
```

Comment: While I have quibbles, such as using backticks rather than `$(...)` and the magic constant `29`, this answer does what the O.P. wanted.

Comment: @KurtisRader Do you have a specific concern with the use of backticks here, or more like a "you should get in the habit of preferring `$(...)`"?

Comment: This is the correct answer indeed. However, I have figured out that my account name has an index that is not continuous so multiple numbers are missing. How, can I have a list of numbers and loop through them instead?

Comment: @JoseRamon You could do `for aid in $(cat list.txt)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The `$(...)` form has fewer quoting quirks than the backtick form and is easier to read. The backtick form should never be used unless you are actually using a shell that doesn't support `$(...)`; which is unlikely in 2024.